# Не удается создать объект типа "AppDbContext" во время создании миграции

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

В PowerShell ввожу:
`dotnet ef migrations add _initial`

Получаю:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: WebApplication3.Domain.Repositories.DataManager Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: WebApplication3.Domain.Repositories.DataManager': A suitable constructor for type 'WebApplication3.Domain.Repositories.DataManager' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.)
Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Проблема: Не удается создать миграцию.

**AppDbContext.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication3.Domain
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<TextField> TextFields { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ServiceItem> ServiceItems { get; set; }
        ...

    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //подключаем конфиг из appsettings.json
            Configuration.Bind("Project", new Config());

            //подключаем нужный функционал приложения в качестве сервисов
            services.AddTransient<ITextFieldsRepository, EFTextFieldsRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IServiceItemsRepository, EFServiceItemsRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<DataManager>();

            //Подключаем контекст БД
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Config.ConnectionString));

            //Настройка identity системы
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(opts =>
            {
                opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                opts.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            //настраиваем authenitication cookie
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "myCompanyAuth";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/accessdenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });


            //добавляем поддержку контроллеров и представлений (MVC)
            services.AddControllersWithViews().
                //выставляем совместимость с asp.net core 3.0
                SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            //порядок регистрации middleware очень важен

            //в процессе разработки нам важно видеть подробную информацию об ошибках
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseRouting();

            //подключение аутенификации и авторизации
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            //подключаем поддержку статичных файлов в приложении (css, js e.t.c)
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //регистрируем нужные нам маршруты (ендпоинты)
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Почитайте текст ошибки внимательно, там написано в каком классе у вас проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Смог решить таким способом:

1. Установил EntityFrameworkCore.Tools в NuGet
2. В Package Manage Console ввёл команду Add-Migration название миграции. После этого миграция создалась.

Надеюсь твоё решение было без установки дополнительного пакета и с помощью ввода другой команды в Power Shell.

А теперь я смог решить проблему нормальным способом. У меня в строке подключения была ошибка, проверь её внимательно.

Comment: Я смог ее решить таким способом:
 1) Установил EntityFrameworkCore.Tools в NuGet
 2) В Package Manage Console ввёл команду Add-Migration название миграции
После этого миграция создалась, надеюсь твоё решение было без установки дополнительного пакета и с помощью ввода другой команды в Power Shell

Comment: А теперь я смог решить проблему нормальным способом) У меня в строке подключения была ошибка, проверь её внимательно

Comment: Не пишите комментариев, правте ответ кнопкой "править".